# Get the right amount of space to make an ascii square batchfile [BATCH]

Tags: batch-file, ascii, space

I'm trying to make an ASCII square without deforming it with an X value of letter, example

If I'm doing `pseudo = test1` I gonna get:

```
set pseudo=test1 
=
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│» Pseudo : Test1                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

But I want :

```
set pseudo=test1 
=
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│» Pseudo : Test1                                                                          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

And this for any number of letter like:

```
set pseudo=dqzdijqzodijqzdoij
=
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│» Pseudo : dqzdijqzodijqzdoij                                                             │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I've thought of making a for to count how many there is of letter and subtracting the number of space before printing them with another for, but I don't have the capacities.

Comment: 'I want', and 'I don't have rhe capacities' are not on topic programming code help questions. This site isn't here to write code for you, please make more effort. IMO, the whole idea is a waste of time, there is zero need to draw childish lines around text in a text based interface

Comment: yes, i have my reason to do this, secondly : i've tried to code the thing for hours but i dont have the capacities, i written what i've tried but i wasnt able to do it with my capacities

Comment: Well you're going to have to learn, because we are not your free tutoring or coding service.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows 10 or later, you can use the Console Virtual Terminal Escape sequences to turn on DEC Line Drawing characters for your box. You can read more here:

[Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences)

Here is a small example:

```
@echo off
REM Set an escape character
for /f %%e in ('echo prompt $E^|cmd') do set "\e=%%e"
REM Sets a line drawing character
set "_line=%\e%(0"
REM Sets it back to normal text.
set "_text=%\e%(B"
set /P "=%_line%"<NUL
echo    lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
echo    x    %_text%Pseudo : Test 1%_line% 
echo    mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq%_text%
REM Example showing how to change the cursor position and echo text.
echo %\e%[5;13H test
pause
```

EDIT: Editing to provide an example of how to change cursor position.

Comment: I mean if VT100 sequences are allowed, just draw the box first and then `ESC[2;13H` to move the cursor to the right place.

Comment: hello, the problem is not here, if you look all the code block, at the right there is a line, so with this code i'm getting https://prnt.sc/vqSTP-nNv6gE instead of https://prnt.sc/XhkvIll0bGSP

Comment: SomethingDark by imagining it, it would be logic yes, but i dont know how to use these, i'm an beginner :/

Comment: That's why I included the code for it in my comment :) (although with this particular sample code, you'd use `%\e%` instead of `ESC`, and I'm also assuming that you're starting with a blank screen; you'd have to change the `2` to whatever row you want the text to be on.)

Comment: You will need to manually adjust the spacing between the DEC and ASCII characters and run the script until you get the characters to line up the way you need.

Comment: How do i do this ? ```echo %\e%[5;13H test``` ?

Comment: If you were to put `echo %\e%[5;13H test` into the line before `pause` in the script I included above, it would move the cursor position to 5th line and 13th column and then print out the word test.

Comment: I dont understand wtf, can you show me an exemple ?

Comment: @Dapkz Please see my edited example above. Add the small example to a new batch file and run it to see how it works.